# Posible Error de PHP al intentar acceder a una web por CMS Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, joomla3

(antes de nada agradecería cualquier tipo de edición en título o contexto ya que no se conceptuar cada cosa relacionada con esto ya que apenas tengo un mes de experiencia en estos temas)

Llevo desde el jueves pasado intentando ver mi página web que funcionaba en un ubuntu 16.04 en un ubuntu 14.04 en el cual estando vacío, he instalado apache2, mysql5.6, php5 y php7 y por último phpmyadmin. Tras varios errores en los pasos de instalación he conseguido solucionar el último que era un problema de permisos a la hora de poner localhost e intentar acceder a mi página, al solucionar ese. Ahora simplemente veo en toda la ventana del navegador la palabra "Error" situada en la parte superior izquierda y nada más, si le doy al depurador de chrome tengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

He mirado error.log pero en relación a esto no me salta información y no se por donde pueden ir los tiros, he buscado bastante por internet pero no encuentro nada en claro. Pongo imagen con la info de lo que se usa actualmente, cualquier cosa más que necesitéis me decís.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, también decir que estuve trabajando con php7.1 en la máquina anterior y en esta no se porqué teniendo instalado varias versiones de php me coge la más baja. Si creéis que pudiese ser este el error agradecería también saber como cambiarlo, he encontrado información que he llevado a cabo pero no se me cambia.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: leí toda la pregunta y no entendí que tenia que ver joomla, no me quedó claro el error

Comment: La pregunta era ver si alguno sabía alguna remota posibilidad del porqué me daba el error 500. La página ya está funcionando, lo que hice fue volver a reinstalar varias veces y cambiar la ruta de la carpeta que quería mostrar, etc. La verdad que hice tantas cosas que no se exactamente como lo corregí, si creéis que debo cerrarla lo haré, ya que no encontré nada en claro, pero gracias por responder aunque sea después de tanto tiempo. Un abrazo.